# Universal method for setting ViewState/Session for passed variable and value?

Tags: c#, asp.net

What I have now is code for setting ViewState or Session of desired variable:

```
 if (ViewState["currentPage"] != null)
        {
            currentPage = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["currentPage"].ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            currentPage = 0;
            ViewState["currentPage"] = currentPage.ToString();
        }
```

currentPage field is global with default value of zero in CodeBehind (public int currentPage = 0;) and therefore its initial value is zero whenever the page is loaded. So I wrote these few lines to save its last value. Just to mention that wherever currentPage value is changed in CodeBehind, I added 
"ViewState["currentPage"] = currentPage.ToString();" in line after.

What I want is universal function that takes two arguments, variable and value, for setting ViewState according to code above. So if necessary, I can just call method, something like that: setViewState(currentPage, 0)

Answer (score 0):

is there a need for you to have the variable as an input parameter - what is wrong with simple creating a function in a class somewhere in your application and passing the value in then returning the created value ? i.e.

```
public int setViewState(int value) {
  //return and set value here?
}
```

so would be used like currentValue= setViewState(50);

Comment: But what if there is a need in future, to call this function and set the ViewState of another field, not exactlly "currentPage" ?  Your approach is only for one field, but what I wanted is universal method, so it should have one more parameter, that would reference to desired field.

Answer (score 0):

I think the difficulty you are going to have with a global function is that ViewState is local to the page.

A couple of things that might help you though:

1. Don't forget ViewState is an object so you don't have to do the ToString
2. You could put the necessary code in a Property like this:

   ```
   public int? TestInt {
       get { return ViewState["TestInt"] as int?; }
       set { ViewState["TestInt"] = value; }
   }
   ```

I like this approach because its very obvious what the code is doing, particuarly as I try to minimize ViewState usage where possible.

Comment: 1) As I am pretty new in programming, don't know why I don't have to do ToString on object. Can you explain it in few words?

2) What means "?" sign near int? For me, it's not so obvious what code is doing :)

Comment: The int? is the same as System.Nullable<int> it just means that the variable can contain null. the as int? means that if ViewState["TestInt"] is not set, then it will be null and null will be returned. Without using nullables, you would need a little bit more code to avoid an error (and maybe would return zero instead of null). Regarding datatypes and ToString etc, the C# compiler is pretty good at helping you. I would recommend Resharper (or wait for VS2015) as this will tell you when you don't need to use things like ToString().